# Azure CLI: 'azure sql db show' returning `HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable`

Tags: azure, azure-cli

In Azure CLI I was trying `azure sql db`  to manage databases:

- `azure sql db create server1 db1` - works fine, creates the database
- `azure sql db show server1 db1` - fails with

  Service Unavailable

  ### Service Unavailable

  ---

  HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.
- `azure sql db delete server1 db1` - fails with

  Service Unavailable

  ### Service Unavailable

  ---

  HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.

I tried with intentionally mistaken server name, the result is as expected:

```
info:    Executing command sql db show
Administrator password: *************
+ Getting SQL server databases
error:   getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND <wrong server>.database.windows.net <wrong server>.database.windows.net:443
error:   Error information has been recorded to .azure\azure.err
error:   sql db show command failed
```

I wonder what would be the cause of `503. The service is unavailable` error. Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same problem.
Apparently it's a known issue on the Azure CLI and they plan to fix it soon when they will rewrite the CLI.

https://github.com/Azure/azure-xplat-cli/issues/2090

As a work around you can try the Azure Power Shell commands.